# Java: Converting a double to a String

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have a double whose value is 10,000,000.00 (ten millions). I have to
convert it to a `String`. When using the method `toString` I am getting the `String`
"1.0E7" which is correct following the specification. Unfortunately I need
the `String` "10,000,000.00" (or the equivalent depending on the locale).

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try either

NumberFormat  http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

DecimalFormat http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the formatter, you might consider using the `java.math.BigDecimal` class to represent numbers precisely.

Calculations where complete accuracy is required, such as financial calculations, are best performed with `BigDecimal`. Floating point math is better for engineering, graphics, and other mathematical computations where some accuracy can be sacrificed for speed.

Answer (score 4):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    double aDouble = 10000000.00;
    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    String aString = Double.toString(aDouble);
    System.out.println(nf.parse(aString));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into "DecimalFormat".  It lets you format the output pretty much however you want!