# Java Double to String conversion without formatting

Tags: java, string, format, double

I have the number 654987. Its an ID in a database. I want to convert it to a string. 
The regular Double.ToString(value) makes it into scientific form, 6.54987E5. Something I dont want.

Other formatting functions Ive found checks the current locale and adds appropriate thousand separators and such. Since its an ID, I cant accept any formatting at all.

How to do it?

[Edit] To clarify: Im working on a special database that treats all numeric columns as doubles. **Double is the only (numeric) type I can retrieve from the database.**

Comment: See the top answer in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045/sprintf-equivalent-in-java
Answers the same question.

Comment: 654987 is an integer, not a double. Did you mean something else?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521122/java-converting-a-double-to-a-string/1521324#1521324

Comment: @JuanZe: Setting a locale causes thousand separators to be added, which I dont want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use Long:

```
long id = 654987;
String str = Long.toString(id);
```

Answer (score 33):

Use a fixed [`NumberFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) (specifically a [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)):

```
double value = getValue();
String str = new DecimalFormat("#").format(value);
```

alternatively simply cast to `int` (or `long` if the range of values it too big):

```
String str = String.valueOf((long) value);
```

But then again: why do you have an integer value (i.e. a "whole" number) in a `double` variable in the first place?

Comment: Reason for double is that Im working with a database that treats all numeric columns as doubles.

Comment: If you cast double to long, sometimes the value changes. For ex: `((long) ((double)25891000000002001L))` becomes `25891000000002000L`

Answer (score 6):

If it's an integer id in the database, use an Integer instead.  Then it will format as an integer.

Comment: In a perfect world, of course, but the reason for the question is that Im trying to work around limits in the database; the only (numeric) type it can store is a double.

Answer (score 6):

How about `String.valueOf((long)value);`

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
Long.toString(value)
```

or

```
new String(value)
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `""+value`! It's a hack and doesn't convey the intent in any way. I'd say it's bad style at the very least.

Comment: Ok :) Replaced that with "new String(value)".

Comment: new String(value) will have the same problem as the question mentions, if value is a `double`.

Comment: `new String(long)` does not exist in Java

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use

```
double value = getValue();

NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
f.setGroupingUsed(false);

String strVal = f.format(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are storing is an ID (i.e. something used only to identify another entity, whose actual numeric value has no significance) then you shouldn't be using Double to store it. Precision will almost certainly screw you.

If your database doesn't allow integer values then you should stored IDs as strings. If necessary make the string the string representation of the integer you want to use. With appropriate use of leading zeros you can make the alphabetic order of the string the same as the numeric order of the ints.

That should get you round the issue.

Comment: Sadly, both the database and its datatypes are set. The column I am to handle is a double and there is nothing I can do about it. When the database is read I of course quickly convert it into an int for internal use (or a string as you suggest). It doesnt really matter since the problem is the actual conversion, as I cant change the content or layout of the database.

Answer (score 0):

What about Long.toString((long)value) ?

Answer (score -3):

```
    double d = 56789;
    String s = d+"";
```

Comment: Doesnt that call Double.toString(d)? Which by default, if Im not mistaken, adds both scientific notation and thousand separators (if necessary).