# How to print a double in standard instead of scientific notation?

Tags: java

How can I print a `double` in standard notation?

```
double h = 104857600 - 32;
System.out.println(h);
```

Result:

```
1.04857568E8
```

Desired result:

```
104857568
```

Comment: usually, absolute value is something else (i.e. `abs(-2) = 2`), can you explain a little more

Comment: I think he means absolute value in a sense, readable number i.e not in (number)E(power)

Comment: I found another link on Stack Overflow for your reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631091/java-double-to-string-conversion-without-formatting Please mark the question as answered if the last reply helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

```
System.out.printf("%.0f", h);
```

The `0` is the *precision*, you can modify it.

**Edit:**

If you want to store it as a `String`, you can use `String.format("%.0f", h)`.

Comment: dear @Christian, thank you it work, but how can i store the absolute value in string variable?

Comment: @user2818462 Please stop referring to this as the absolute value.  [Absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) is something entirely different.

Comment: What do you mean by *absolute value*? There is a method `String.format()`, that works like `printf()`.