# Incompatible types; String cannot be converted to double : JAVA TOKEN

Tags: java, file-io, token

[EDIT] to clarify this is a different question: My question is about parsing String to double for a token to accept it and none of the answers to this question [Java Double to String conversion without formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631091/java-double-to-string-conversion-without-formatting) match my criteria.

I have got a file in the following format:

```
A B 10
A C 12
A D 8
B D 5
B E 2
...
```

Following is the code for storing the above data in arraylist. However it is only storing the start node, end node, but not the cost.

```
List<Node1> list = new ArrayList<Node1>();
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
  list.add(new Node1(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2])); // Error at tokens[2]              
}
```

Following is my Node1 class

```
class Node1 {
   String start, end;
   double cost;

    public Node1(String start, String end, double cost){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getStartNode() {
        return start;
    }

    public String getEndNode(){
        return end;
    }

    public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
}
```

It is giving me an **ERROR**  at `tokens[2]` as following

```
 Incompatible types; String cannot be converted to double
```

I understand the error as, token is expecting String but it found double (cost) but I am not sure how to fix this. Won't tokens compatible to read double or what? If not, what should I be using instead of tokens[2] to store my double value?
I have tried googling, but can't seem to find any solution.
Sorry I am new to this stuff. Please bear with me!

Comment: try `Double.parseDouble(tokens[2])`

Comment: `tokens` is a String array. It does not store *any* doubles. Thus you need to parse your token as a double. Most simple way: `Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);`

Comment: @arhimed Yes I tried it now, this is not giving me any error but it is still not storing the numerical values in the arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[] tokens = line.split(" ");` creates an array of strings, but your node class is expecting a double for the third value. 
Try

```
list.add(new Node1(tokens[0], tokens[1], Double.parseDouble(tokens[2])));
```

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation!

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the last argument in your constructor to a double.

```
list.add(new Node1(tokens[0], tokens[1], Double.parseDouble(tokens[2])));
```

You could also override the constructor.

```
public Node1(String start, String end, String cost) {
  this(start, end, Double.parseDouble(cost));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Double.parseDouble(...)

```
List<Node1> list = new ArrayList<Node1>();
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
  list.add(new Node1(tokens[0], tokens[1], Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]))); // Error at tokens[2]              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
List<Node1> list = new ArrayList<Node1>();
   while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
      list.add(new Node1(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]));             
   }
```

To:

```
List<Node1> list = new ArrayList<Node1>();
   while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
      list.add(new Node1(tokens[0], tokens[1], Double.parseDouble(tokens[2])));              
   }
```